# Jquery select next element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the next menu structure.

```
<li class="menu-422"><a href="item-1" title="">Item 1</a></li>
<li class="menu-444"><a href="item-2" title="">Item 2</a></li>
<li class="menu-449"><a href="item-3" title="">Item 3</a></li>
<li class="menu-452"><a href="item-4" title="">Item 4</a></li>
```

In this structure the items (the a-tag) have background. I want to change the background of the next item on hover event. If I'm over the Item 2 I want to change the background of the Item 3. I tried it with jQuery, but I didn't find the appropriate code.

```
jQuery("#mymenu li a").hover(function() {
  jQuery(this).next("li a").css('background', 'none');
}
```

I tried it with nextAll, with full selector path, but I can't select the next element.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Upon hover, you want to go up to the parent `li`, then use `next()` to get to the next `li`, then `find('a')` inside of that `li`:

```
$("#mymenu li a").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().find("a").css('background', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting the anchors you can just select `li` and attach `hover` event on it. And in the hover just use `next` method to get the next `li` element and change the background. I am assuming you dont have background set to the anchor's because I am changing the background of the li element.

```
$("#mymenu li").hover(function() {
    $(this).next().css('background', 'none');
    //If you want to change the background of anchor try this
    //$(this).next().find('a').css('background', 'none');
}
```